# How can I get clean Gradle output on Travis CI?

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

Example output for a normal build on Travis CI using Gradle:

https://travis-ci.org/2m/gradle-travis-test/builds/8579228

Gradle seems to think that the console has the same capabilities as a normal ANSI console, while in reality it only supports some of those features. Specifically, it seems to support colors, but not updating/replacing text (it's append-only).

How can I tell Gradle to use "plain" console output?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Gradle automatically detects the terminal type based on the $TERM environment variable (and a few other layers in between). Setting `TERM=dumb` causes Gradle to use plain console output.

In your .travis.yml file, you should now have something like the following (assuming the Gradle wrapper is used):

```
install:
  - TERM=dumb ./gradlew assemble

script:
  - TERM=dumb ./gradlew check
```

For sample output, see this build:

https://travis-ci.org/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/builds/9639517

Answer (score 20):

The solution of Ralf stopped working for me. Instead I'm now doing:

```
env:
  - TERM=dumb

script:
  - ./gradlew assemble -x test
```

Comment: What issue did you get?

Comment: I meant that the solution below didn't work anymore for me. sorry for the confusing

Comment: This works great, and seems to be the preferred way to do it: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Set-environment-variables .

Comment: One can still get colored test output: https://github.com/mendhak/Gradle-Travis-Colored-Output

Comment: This will cause the entire script to have that variable set, rather than just the one command, which may or may not be desirable. What went wrong with the `TERM=dumb ./gradlew ...` solution? That certainly should work, and it WFM.